# Storyboard Problems with Xcode 6

Tags: ide, xcode6

[image]

I opened up a project I was working on and have found that all of the items that I have added to the main.storyboard are greyed out as in the screen shot. When I look at the Main.storyboard, it doesn't display anything. The Label that is in black is a label that I added to test that I can add something to the screen. When I run the application it works as expected.

How do I get the greyed out items to not be greyed out any more?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: I got some help from Chris. The storyboard got switched from any / Compact to any / any. Once I switched it back, the problem went away. Thanks for the help Chris.